# inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, .net, listview

i am displaying version(WrmVersion) value in  a listview ,,but here i given one codition
means if version(WrmVersion) is null i am displaying 'None'(ResourcePolicyAvailSystemsLVI.m_nullString="None"),,but now i am getting an error

> 'Ship.Controls.ResourcePolicySystemsControl.ResourcePolicyAvailSystemsLVI.m_nullString' is inaccessible due to its protection level   F:\test\Ship\Controls\ResourcePolicySystemsControl.cs   81  70  Ship.Controls

```
protected override void OnUpdate()
         {
            string func = "ResourcePolicySystemsLVI.OnUpdate";
            try
            {
               if(Data != null)
               {
                  Text = base.Data.Name;
                  if(SubItems.Count == 1)
                  {
                      if (Data.WrmVersion == null)
                      {
                          SubItems.Add(ResourcePolicyAvailSystemsLVI.m_nullString);
                      }
                      else
                          **SubItems.Add(((IResourcePolicy)Data).WrmVersion.ToString());**
                     SubItems.Add(((IResourcePolicy)Data).ResourcePolicyEnabled.ToString());
                     SubItems.Add(((IResourcePolicy)Data).ResourcePolicyCurrent.ToString());
                     //SubItems.Add(((IResourcePolicy)Data).WrmVersion.ToString());
                     //SubItems.Add(Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Unisys\Single Point Operations Windows Resource Monitor", "CurrentVersion", "0").ToString()); 
                  }
                  else
                  {
                     SubItems[1].Text = ((IResourcePolicy)Data).ResourcePolicyEnabled.ToString();
                     SubItems[2].Text = ((IResourcePolicy)Data).ResourcePolicyCurrent.ToString();
                  }
               }
               base.OnUpdate();
```

Comment: Re your comment - I don't know if that means you are "sorted", or if you are still lost...? For example... just add a property (see update)

Answer (score 11):

Well, what **is** the protection level of `ResourcePolicyAvailSystemsLVI.m_nullString` ? And where is your code in relation? It will be inaccessible if, for example

- it is `private` and you're in an unrelated class
- it is `protected` and you're not in a subclass
- it is `internal` and you're in a different assembly without [`InternalsVisibleTo]`
- it is `protected internal` and both of the two above apply

To be honest, it **looks** like a field, and fields *generally* aren't `public` - so it wouldn't amaze me if somebody has changed the accessibility, perhaps adding a public static property to wrap it - or simply changed the name (although that would give a different error). Try looking for `ResourcePolicyAvailSystemsLVI.NullString` or similar (in intellisense / object-browser).

---

Re your comment; you have:

```
private static string m_nullString =
    Managers.ControlStrings.GetString("ManagedDeviceWizard.None");
```

so just add:

```
public static string NullString {get {return m_nullString;}}
```

and change your calling code to use `ResourcePolicyAvailSystemsLVI.NullString`.

Comment: exactly thats my mistake,,actually there are two Listviews there i copied that from second listview to first listview where listview defined class is changed
more over need to declare the string

means like this      public class ResourcePolicySystemsLVI : BaseLVItem
      {
          #region Fields

          private static string m_nullString = Managers.ControlStrings.GetString("ManagedDeviceWizard.None");

          #endregion Fields

Answer (score 2):

You can't add:

```
  ResourcePolicyAvailSystemsLVI.m_nullString
```

because the scope of that member is either private or internal.

You need to make it public (or ideally, expose it via a property).

Comment: exactly thats my mistake,,actually there are two Listviews there i copied that from second listview to first listview where listview defined class is changed
more over need to declare the string

means like this      public class ResourcePolicySystemsLVI : BaseLVItem
      {
          #region Fields

          private static string m_nullString = Managers.ControlStrings.GetString("ManagedDeviceWizard.None");

          #endregion Fields